# function call gives me "pending.."

Tags: evm, pending-transactions, random

I have a problem with a function in a lottery contract.
given that library for pseudorandom:

```
library Random {
/*
 * @dev startingValue is inclusive, endingValue is inclusive
 * naive implementation! Do not use in production
 * ie if 1, 10, rand int can include 1-10
 */
function naiveRandInt(uint256 _startingValue, uint256 _endingValue)
    internal
    view
    returns (uint256)
{
    // hash of the given block when blocknumber is one of the 256 most recent blocks; otherwise returns zero
    // create random value from block number; use previous block number just to make sure we aren't on 0
    uint randomInt = uint(blockhash(block.number - 1));
    // convert this into a number within range
    uint range = _endingValue - _startingValue + 1; // add 1 to ensure it is inclusive within endingValue

    randomInt = randomInt % range; // modulus ensures value is within range
    randomInt += _startingValue; // now shift by startingValue to ensure it is >= startingValue

    return randomInt;
}
```

}

I wrote this chooseWinner function:

```
function chooseWinner() public returns (address winner, uint256 ) {
    require(ticketCounter >= 1, "no tickets are sold");
    require(block.timestamp > endTimestamp, "Lottery isn't over");
    require(winnerWasChosen == false, "Function was already called");

    winnerTicket = Random.naiveRandInt(0, ticketCounter);
    _winner = s_ticket[winnerTicket];
    prize = ticketCost * ticketCounter;

    if(erc20.transfer( _winner, prize)) {
        winnerWasChosen == true;
    }

    else {revert();}

    return (_winner, winnerTicket);
    
}
```

but when contract is deployed and I call chooseWinner, evm tells "pending.."
What's wrong?

UPDATE (all the code):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "./Token.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";



library Random {
    /*
     * @dev startingValue is inclusive, endingValue is inclusive
     * naive implementation! Do not use in production
     * ie if 1, 10, rand int can include 1-10
     */
    function naiveRandInt(uint256 _startingValue, uint256 _endingValue)
        internal
        view
        returns (uint256)
    {
        // hash of the given block when blocknumber is one of the 256 most recent blocks; otherwise returns zero
        // create random value from block number; use previous block number just to make sure we aren't on 0
        uint randomInt = uint(blockhash(block.number - 1));
        // convert this into a number within range
        uint range = _endingValue - _startingValue + 1; // add 1 to ensure it is inclusive within endingValue

        randomInt = randomInt % range; // modulus ensures value is within range
        randomInt += _startingValue; // now shift by startingValue to ensure it is >= startingValue

        return randomInt;
    }
}

contract Lottery {
    IERC20 public erc20;
    uint256 public startTimestamp;
    uint256 public endTimestamp;
    uint256 public ticketCost;
    uint256 public ticketCounter;
    uint256 public winnerTicket;
    uint256 private prize;
    bool internal winnerWasChosen;
    address public _winner;

    mapping(address => uint256) s_players;
    mapping(uint256 => address) s_ticket;
    mapping(address => uint256) public _balances;


    constructor(uint256 _startTimestamp, uint256 _endTimestamp, uint256 _ticketCost, IERC20 _token) {
        startTimestamp = _startTimestamp;
        endTimestamp = _endTimestamp;
        ticketCost = _ticketCost;
        erc20 = IERC20(_token);
        
    }

    function buyTicket() public returns (uint256 ticketId)  {
        require(erc20.balanceOf(msg.sender) > ticketCost, "not enough balance");
        require(block.timestamp > startTimestamp, "Lottery is not started yet");
        require(endTimestamp > block.timestamp, "Lottery is over");
        require(s_players[msg.sender] == 0, "Already got one ticket");
         
        erc20.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), ticketCost);
            ticketCounter++;
            s_players[msg.sender] = ticketCounter;
            s_ticket[ticketCounter] = msg.sender;
            return ticketCounter;
    }

    function chooseWinner() public returns (address winner ) {
        require(ticketCounter >= 1, "no tickets are sold");
        require(block.timestamp > endTimestamp, "Lottery isn't over");
        require(winnerWasChosen == false, "Function was already called");

        winnerTicket = Random.naiveRandInt(1, ticketCounter);
        _winner = s_ticket[winnerTicket];
        prize = ticketCost * ticketCounter;

        erc20.transfer(_winner, prize); 


        return (_winner );
        
    }

    function getStartLottery() public view returns (bool) {
        return (block.timestamp >= startTimestamp); 
    }

   function getEndLottery() public view returns (bool) {
       return (block.timestamp >= endTimestamp);  
    }

    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint) {
        return ticketCost;  
    }

    function getTimestamp() public view returns (uint256) {
        return block.timestamp;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _addr) public view returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[_addr];
    }
    
    function getPrize() public view returns (uint256){ 
        return ticketCost * ticketCounter;
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you calling the function? Do you have a script that calls it or do you have it included in the interface?

Could you add the code that you use to call it to the question?

Comment: Please, can you share all your smart contract code?

Comment: I added all my code in the post @Kerry99

Comment: Actually I'm calling it from remix buttons but the idea is to call it through an interface @OneThunder

Comment: @Federico what environment are you using to try to interact with your smart contract?

Comment: Remix VM (London) @OneThunder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `Remix VM`, the smart contract is unable to get the `blockhash`. I think your example should work as expected on a public test network or in [Ganache](https://trufflesuite.com/ganache/).